# How to dynamically create form controls in a form control and display them along other data within an ngFor?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, forms, ngfor

I want to run an ngFor over an array of objects in order to populate tags with each objects corresponding data AND, preferably in the same ngFor, I would like to add a form control for each object in the aforementioned array. I also want to be able to add a new form control for each NEW object added. To my understanding, the logic for doing the above is all working just fine, my issue is being able to appropriately loop over both the array of objects and the array of form controls simultaneously?

Below is the logic for creating a new form control for each object in the array:

Firstly, I have initialized the FormArray within a FormGroup inside my ngOnInit as follows:

```
stockForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stockForm = new FormGroup({
      'quantities': new FormArray([])
    })
    this.getBranchStock();
  }
```

I have then declared two methods, one for getting the controls, and another to create the controls for the above mentioned FormArray.

The first method mentioned (to get the controls):

```
getQuantityControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.stockForm.get('quantities')).controls;
  }
```

Then, the second method mentioned (to create the controls):

```
createNewQuantity() {
    const quantity = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    (<FormArray>this.stockForm.get('quantities')).push(quantity)
  }
```

The second method "createNewQuantity", pushes a new form control to the form array. This method is called initially when I receive the array of objects I had spoken about earlier. I call the "createNewQuantity" method for each object in the array by running it through a for loop as can be seen below:

```
product: BranchProduct[];

 getBranchStock() {
    const id = this.branchService.getBranchId();
    id.subscribe(
      (resp: any) => {
        this.subs.add(this.branchService.getBranchStock(resp).subscribe(
          (resp: any) => {
            this.product = resp;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.product.length; i++) {
              this.createNewQuantity();
            }
          },
          (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
        )
      })
  }
```

After the above executes, I have a form control for each object in the array. This works as intended (as far as I understand). My real issue lies in the way I run the ngFor loop. I need to loop over all of the objects in the 'product' array as seen above, AND each newly created form control in the 'quantities' FormArray. I do not know how to set up the template to get this to work. What I have tried is the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="stockForm" *ngIf="stockForm">
              <mat-card *ngFor="let item of product; let quantity of getQuantityControls(); let i = index;" class="enter-quantity-card">
                  <mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="7:1">
                    
                      <!-- Product Id Tile-->
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                        <div class="data-wrapper">
                          <h3>Product ID: <span class="data-text"><strong>{{item.ProductId}}</strong></span></h3>
                        </div>
                      </mat-grid-tile>

                      <!-- Product Type Tile -->
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                        <div class="data-wrapper">
                          <h3>Product Type: <span class="data-text"><strong>{{item.ProductTypeName}}</strong></span></h3>
                        </div>
                      </mat-grid-tile>

                      <!-- Product Name Tile-->
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                        <div class="data-wrapper">
                          <h3>Product Name: <span class="data-text"><strong>{{item.ProductName}}</strong></span></h3>
                        </div>
                      </mat-grid-tile>

                      <!-- Quantity On Hand Tile-->
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                        <div class="data-wrapper">
                          <h3>Quantity on Hand: <span class="data-text"><strong>{{item.QuantityOnHand}}</strong></span>
                          </h3>
                        </div>
                      </mat-grid-tile>

                      <!-- Quantity Selected Tile (Using Form Array) -->
                      <mat-grid-tile>
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput [formControlName]="i">
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </mat-grid-tile>

                  </mat-grid-list>
              </mat-card>
          </form>
```

The above does not work due to the fact that I have both the `let item of product` and `let quantity of getQuantityControls(); let i = index;` declarations in ONE ngFor. This is not allowed by Typescript as the new AbstractControl cannot be of type product array. However, I simply have no clue as to how else I could structure the template for this to work. The form itself looks something like this:

[image]

So as you can see, each object 'has its own' form control. However I don't know how to make each form control unique in order for each control to be validated separately. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about getting each product using `index` instead of looping through the `product` array? You'd have a single loop: `*ngFor="let quantity of getQuantityControls(); let i = index;"` and then use the index like this: `{{product[i].ProductTypeName}}`

Comment: This is great. Simple solution, thank you so much. I also just needed to add `formArrayName = "quantities"` in the same `mat-card` tag the ngFor is situated in. If you would like, you could post your comment as an answer and id be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about getting each product using `index` instead of looping through the `product` array?

You'd have a single loop: `*ngFor="let quantity of getQuantityControls(); let i = index;"` and then use the `index` like this: `{{product[i].ProductTypeName}}`